# SafeAreas misbehave when presenting a UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I need to present a UIViewController (ViewControllerTwo) that only supports ".landscape" orientations from another UIViewController (ViewControllerOne) that only supports ".portrait" orientation. If you check the .gif below, you will notice that when the transition occurs it shrinks the content of "ViewControllerOne" and when you dismiss "ViewControllerTwo" the same happens.

The reason why this happens is related to the change of safe areas, which in portrait are different from landscape and vice versa. But if we override supportedInterfaceOrientations of "ViewControllerOne" to just support ".portrait" it should not be informed of the safe area changes if these changes relate to an unsupported orientation right?

Is this a bug/limitation from iOS?

```
(NO) -> What is the right way to handle this scenario?

(YES) -> What workaround do you recommend to solve this issue in the meantime?
```

You can check the Example Project here: https://github.com/mantuness/ExampleProject

Check the GIF below:

[image]